# Is there a way to use a list like a template to create another list?

Tags: c#, list, oop

I have a Route class that has a set of Instructions (also a class) stored in a list.

```
List<Route> RouteTemplates = new List<Route>() { RouteTemplateA, RouteTemplateB, RouteTemplateC };

List<Route> CompletedRoutes = new List<Route>();
```

All of the routes stored in the list have set of instructions

```
RouteTemplateA.Instructions.Add(instr1);
RouteTemplateA.Instructions.Add(instr2);
RouteTemplateA.Instructions.Add(instr3);

RouteTemplateB.Instructions.Add(instr4);
RouteTemplateB.Instructions.Add(instr5);
RouteTemplateB.Instructions.Add(instr6);
```

What I would like to do is add a set of instructions at the end of each route depending on a number of factors,  and then copy it to a new "Completed" list.

```
RouteTemplateA.Instructions.AddRange(finalInstructions1);

CompletedRoutes.Add(RouteTemplateA);
```

Then I want to remove the instructions that I just added so I can add a different set of final instructions, and then save that different route to the CompletedRoutes list:

```
RouteTemplateA.Instructions.RemoveRange(finalInstructions1);

RouteTemplateA.Instructions.AddRange(finalInstructions2);

CompletedRoutes.Add(RouteTemplateA);
```

The problem I am having is when I remove the instructions from RouteTemplate A it is also removing it from  the object stored in the CompletedRoutes list, which I dont want.

I'm wondering if there is a way around this.  Sorry, I am kind of new.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if modifying some items modifies other items - it looks like you use the same object references for different items. Clone objects instead. You must consider cloning both lists (collections) and items. Consider using structs instead of objects if you don't need mutable fields.

Comment: Try using the [`Object.MemberwiseClone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=net-5.0) method to clone your objects to new instances before you make changes.

Comment: This is the signature of `RemoveRange (int index, int count)`, so how does your `RemoveRange(finalInstructions1)` compile? To answer your question: maybe you can create a new list: `new List<Route>(originalList)`. If you now remove an object from `originalList` it is not removed from the other list that was constructed with it. You could do that in `CompletedRoutes.Add`

Comment: You could create a deep copy of the route before adding it to completed routes. That way the object is completely unrelated to the objects you would be removing from the other list

Comment: Thank you for all your repsonses. I went the deep copy route before I asked this question (should have mentioned that).  The problem I had was I have a waypoint list with X, Y coordinate positions that get updated when the user zooms in or out, and the deep copy wiped out the references to this list.  Darn!  I also tried using the new List<Route>(OriginalList) method before, but this only appears to work for simple types and not a complex object like I am working with.

Comment: Unless anybody has ideas, I think my best bet maybe to move everything to SQL.  It would be relatively easy to write about 20-30 insert statements in SQL to add the waypoint instructions to each template.  Was holding off because this is just a POC. That would require me to figure out how to use Entity Framework, which I've only used a couple of times and never from code to DB.